# What is the pythonic way to to resume a loop within a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, resume

I have an python 2.7 application that I am occasionally interrupting.

I am processing a very large data file.  To deal with memory constraints, I have divided up the data file into grids that are identified by an x and y components.  Each grid is processed independently.

It takes a very long time to process so occasionally, I need to stop the processing at a certain point.  Ideally, I would like to update the y_start and x_start and resume the application at the place I left off (without processing a grid that had already been processed).

The main action occurs within a nested for-loop:

```
x_start=0.0
x_step=0.05
x_size=10.0
y_start=0.0
y_step=0.05
y_size=10.0

x_ranges = zip(np.arange(x_start,x_size,x_step), np.arange(x_step+x_start,x_size+x_step,x_step))

y_ranges = zip(np.arange(0.0,y_size,y_step), np.arange(y_step,y_size+y_step,y_step))


for x_min,x_max in x_ranges:
    for y_min,y_max in y_ranges:

        doAction()
```

In the code above, I have the x_start handled.  y_start should only be used for when x_min = x_start.  For all other values of x, it should start at 0.0.

Here's my proposed solution.  Is there a better, more pythonic way:

```
y_ranges_resume = zip(np.arange(y_start,y_size,y_step),np.arange(y_start+y_step,y_size+y_step,y_step)

for x_min,x_max in x_ranges:
    if x_min == x_start:     
        for y_min,y_max in y_ranges_resume:
            doAction()
    else:
        for y_min,y_max in y_ranges:
            doAction()
```

Comment: I think you should explain what you want to achieve, I believe there are more things that can be done with your code that the for loops :)

Comment: Good point.  I'll add details.

Comment: DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), you can use the ternary operator in your for expression, e.g.: `for y_min, y_max in y_ranges_resume if x_min == x_start else y_ranges:`

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Else you can use `while loop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about a more pythonic way, but you could rewrite it like this (in any language really):

```
y_ranges_resume = zip(np.arange(y_start,y_size,y_step),np.arange(y_start+y_step,y_size+y_step,y_step)

for x_min,x_max in x_ranges:
    y_ranges_used = y_ranges
    if x_min == x_start:     
        y_ranges_used = y_ranges_resume

    for y_min,y_max in y_ranges_used:
        doAction()
```

At least then the inner loop is only written once.

Alternatively you could use the ternary, but I error on the side of easier to read rather than smaller code. But for completeness sake you could write the same thing this way:

```
y_ranges_resume = zip(np.arange(y_start,y_size,y_step),np.arange(y_start+y_step,y_size+y_step,y_step)

for x_min,x_max in x_ranges:
    for y_min, y_max in y_ranges_resume if x_min == x_start else y_ranges:
        doAction()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try list comprehension:

```
[[doAction() for y_min,y_max in y_ranges_resume] if x_min == x_start else [doAction() for y_min,y_max in y_ranges] for x_min,xmax in x_ranges]
```

Or you could use a lambda function to simplify the condition

```
correct_y_range = lambda x : y_ranges_resume if x == x_start else y_ranges
[[doAction() for y_min,y_max in correct_y_range(x_min)] for x_min,x_max in x_ranges]
```

Another option with the lambda function (for better readability)

```
correct_y_range = lambda x : y_ranges_resume if x == x_start else y_ranges
for x_min,x_max in x_ranges:
    for y_min, y_max in correct_y_range(x_min):
        doAction()
```

Comment: It's more pythonic :-).  I am trying to avoid using doAction() twice and the brackets make the code more difficult to read.

Comment: I will add another one similar to Aaron's

Comment: Thanks.  That will be helpful.